# Javascript generate dynamic multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Can anyone help me or give me sample/example for javascript code like what I explained?

I have array like this

```
    var obj = [ 
        {rgb : 'val1', x : '10', y : '15'}, 
        {rgb : 'val1', x : '20', y : '25'},  
        {rgb : 'val1', x : '30', y : '35'} 
    ];
```

I want array like this way

```
    var obj = { 
        'val1' : [ {x : '10', y : '15'}, {x : '20', y : '25'},  {x : '30', y : '35'} ] 
    };
```

Comment: Your desired outcome isn't valid - is `val1` supposed to be an array?

Comment: I want to use `val1` as key for main array.

Comment: Your initial object is invalid as well...

Comment: That is not an array. it seems you do not know javascript at all..wouldn't it be best to learn the basics first? try Google lean javascript basics and give it 20 minutes before asking again such basic things.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196)

Comment: I have a canvas with 2 lines drawn on it each with different RGB. I want array of coordinates for each line with RGB as key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var newObj={};
for(var i=0, l = obj.length; i<l; i++){
  if (typeof newObj[obj[i].rgb] === 'undefined')
    newObj[obj[i].rgb] = []; 
  newObj[obj[i].rgb].push({ x: obj[i].x, y: obj[i].y })
}
obj = newObj;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are going to want to do to have a 'map' type structure is this:

```
var obj = {
   'val1': [{x : '10'},{y : '10'}]
}
```

Comment: I dont get this answer?

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the question, isn't he trying to create a map in JavaScript?

Comment: OP is trying to convert a current array of objects to a different format - I dont see how this answer helps?